# Javascript (+) sign concatenates instead of giving sum of variables

Tags: javascript, math

Why when I use this: (assuming `i = 1`)

```
divID = "question-" + i+1;
```

I get **question-11** and not **question-2**?

Comment: javascript first add value of i to string and then 1

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
var divID = "question-" + (i+1)
```

It's a fairly common problem and doesn't just happen in JavaScript. The idea is that `+` can represent *both* concatenation and addition.

Since the + operator will be handled left-to-right the decisions in your code look like this:

- `"question-" + i`: since `"question-"` is a string, we'll do concatenation, resulting in `"question-1"`
- `"question-1" + 1`: since `"queston-1"` is a string, we'll do concatenation, resulting in `"question-11"`.

With `"question-" + (i+1)` it's different:

- since the `(i+1)` is in parenthesis, its value must be calculated before the first `+` can be applied:

  - `i` is numeric, `1` is numeric, so we'll do addition, resulting in `2`
- `"question-" + 2`: since `"question-"` is a string, we'll do concatenation, resulting in `"question-2"`.

Comment: Worked, thanx! but can you tell me what't the difference?

Comment: @IlyaD - [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) relevant operator is Addition which is handled left to right. So it's doing something like: `divID = ("question-" + i) + 1;`

Comment: This dint work in my case eg "Question" + (i + j) it assumed both variables as string, 
better to go with below solution as "question-" + (i*1+j)

Comment: I was surprised just now to find this didn't work: console.log('Add City Row: '+(i+1)); Even with the math in parentheses, it's concatenating them.

Comment: Great description of why this happens.

Answer (score 35):

You may also use this

```
divID = "question-" + (i*1+1);
```

to be sure that `i` is converted to integer.

Answer (score 18):

Use only:

```
divID = "question-" + parseInt(i) + 1;
```

When "n" comes from html input field or is declared as string, you need to use explicit conversion.

```
var n = "1"; //type is string
var frstCol = 5;
lstCol = frstCol + parseInt(n);
```

If "n" is integer, don't need conversion.

```
n = 1; //type is int
var frstCol = 5, lstCol = frstCol + n;
```

Comment: This answer is very wrong.  The problem remains that concatenation and addition are *left-associative*.  That is: `"question-" + parseInt(i) + 1 === ("question-" + parseInt(i)) + 1`.  See Joachim's answer for more details.  Also, `(+i)` is more concise than `parseInt(i)`

Comment: The syntax should have been: `divID = "question-" + (parseInt(i) + 1)`

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. And `parseInt` is not supposed to be called with a number.

Comment: If anything, the syntax should have included `parseInt(i, 10)`. I don’t get how this answer, which _remains completely wrong to this day_, got 21 upvotes.

Comment: The only solution that worked for me, those parens stuff didn't work in my case.

Answer (score 9):

Since you are concatenating numbers on to a string, the whole thing is treated as a string. When you want to add numbers together, you either need to do it separately and assign it to a var and use that var, like this:

```
i = i + 1;
divID = "question-" + i;
```

Or you need to specify the number addition like this:

```
divID = "question-" + Number(i+1);
```

**EDIT**

I should have added this long ago, but based on the comments, this works as well:

```
divID = "question-" + (i+1);
```

Comment: The `Number` is not required, just the parens.

Comment: Yeah, seeing the other answers here I realized that. I am no js guru for sure. I thought you had to cast the addition using Number, but I should have known. JS just seems to be able to "figure it out", which is one of the really cool aspects of the language. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: This is perfect for my needs. Rather than a string literal, I had a variable I assigned from a text input. I'm using `Number` when the variable is initially assigned, and then it doesn't cause other things to be cast to strings.

Answer (score 4):

```
divID = "question-" + parseInt(i+1,10);
```

[check it here](http://jsfiddle.net/u9L8e/), it's a JSFiddle

Comment: You dont need the `parseInt`, just the parens around the number. http://jsfiddle.net/J8rvy/

Comment: +1, just had a lot of trouble with integers in my own project so I am using parseInt too much now hehe

Comment: Never call `parseInt` with a number, only with a string. `parseInt(1e100) === 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative could be using:

```
divID = "question-" + (i - -1);
```

Subtracting a negative is the same as adding, and a minus cannot be used for concatenation

Edit: Forgot that brackets are still necessary since code is read from left to right.

Comment: Forgot to add brackets. Works without parentheses in some cases but not all.

Comment: The only answer that worked for me. Impressive that a language like Javascript can't do easily a simple addition without a trick like that. Tried all the other answers without sucess!

Answer (score 0):

Add brackets

```
divID = "question-" + (i+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

using braces surrounding the numbers will treat as addition instead of concat.

```
divID = "question-" + (i+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get that is the order of precendence of the operators, and the fact that `+` is used to both concatenate strings as well as perform numeric addition.

In your case, the concatenation of "question-" and `i` is happening first giving the string "question=1". Then another string concatenation with "1" giving "question-11".

You just simply need to give the interpreter a hint as to what order of prec endence you want.

```
divID = "question-" + (i+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Joachim Sauer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5961029/2733146) will work in scenarios like this. But there are some instances where adding parentheses won’t help.

For example: You are passing “sum of value of an input element and an integer” as an argument to a function.

```
arg1 = $("#elemId").val();   // value is treated as string
arg2 = 1;
someFuntion(arg1 + arg2);    // and so the values are merged here
someFuntion((arg1 + arg2));  // and here
```

You can make it work by using [`Number()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp)

```
arg1 = Number($("#elemId").val());
arg2 = 1;
someFuntion(arg1 + arg2);
```

or

```
arg1 = $("#elemId").val();
arg2 = 1;
someFuntion(Number(arg1) + arg2);
```

Comment: This answer doesn’t address the question. The question is about `string + number + number` where `number + number` should do addition before concatenating it to the `string`. It is not about `string + number` in general, where `string` is numeric and `+` should always do addition.

Answer (score -1):

```
var divID = "question-" + (parseInt(i)+1);
```

Use this `+` operator behave as `concat` that's why it showing 11.

Answer (score -1):

Care must be taken that `i` is an integer type of variable. In javaScript we don't specify the datatype during declaration of variables, but our initialisation can guarantee that our variable is of a specific datatype.

It is a good practice to initialize variables of declaration:

- In case of integers, `var num = 0;`
- In case of strings, `var str = "";`

Even if your `i` variable is integer, `+` operator can perform concatenation instead of addition.

In your problem's case, you have supposed that `i = 1`, in order to get `2` in addition with `1` try using `(i-1+2)`. Use of `()`-parenthesis will not be necessary.

`-` (minus operator) cannot be misunderstood and you will not get unexpected result/s.

Comment: How variables are initialized is irrelevant here. Parentheses are still needed; it’s the grouping operator that forces a specific operation precedence. Don’t do `i - 1 + 2`; use the `Number` function instead, if `i` isn’t a number.

Answer (score -2):

One place the parentheses suggestion fails is if say both numbers are HTML input variables.
Say a and b are variables and one receives their values as follows (I am no HTML expert but my son ran into this and there was no parentheses solution i.e.

- HTML inputs were intended numerical values for variables a and b, so say the inputs were 2 and 3.
- Following gave string concatenation outputs: a+b displayed 23; +a+b displayed 23; (a)+(b) displayed 23;
- From suggestions above we tried successfully : Number(a)+Number(b) displayed 5; parseInt(a) + parseInt(b) displayed 5.

Thanks for the help just an FYI - was very confusing and I his Dad got yelled at 'that is was Blogger.com's fault" - no it's a feature of HTML input default combined with the 'addition' operator, when they occur together, the default left-justified interpretation of all and any input variable is that of a string, and hence the addition operator acts naturally in its dual / parallel role now as a concatenation operator since as you folks explained above it is left-justification type of interpretation protocol in Java and Java script thereafter. Very interesting fact. You folks offered up the solution, I am adding the detail for others who run into this.

Comment: This answer doesn’t address the question. The question is about `string + number + number` where `number + number` should do addition before concatenating it to the `string`. It is not about `string + number` in general, where `string` is numeric and `+` should always do addition. `<input type="number">` has `valueAsNumber`, so this isn’t specifically about HTML. `praseInt` should be called with the radix argument; `Number` is preferred. `+` isn’t the addition operator when it doesn’t do addition.

Answer (score -2):

Simple as easy ... every input type if not defined in HTML is considered as string. Because of this the Plus "+" operator is concatenating.

Use parseInt(i) than the value of "i" will be casted to Integer.

Than the "+" operator will work like addition.

In your case do this :-

```
divID = "question-" + parseInt(i)+1;
```

Comment: Never call `parseInt` with a number, only with a string. `parseInt(1e100) === 1`.