# Javascript + operator vs - operator

Tags: javascript

I am puzzled by this [snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/QXtqC/2/):

```
var n1 = 5-"4";
var n2 = 5+"4";

alert(n1);
alert(n2);
```

​I understand that n1 is 1. That is because a minus operator would convert the string "4" into number and subtract it from 5.
But why do we get 54 in case of + operator?

Can someone explain this difference between + and = operators to me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript (+) sign concatenates instead of giving sum of variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961000/javascript-sign-concatenates-instead-of-giving-sum-of-variables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By type conversion any `+` expression, that contains a strings, will result in a string. Thus all operands (in your case `5`) will be converted to a string, before executing the concatenation.

`-` on the other hand is just an arithmetic operand, thus `"4"` is converted to an integer and the calculation is performed as you expect.

Comment: Thanks guys. I later looked in the spec and it says the same thing: http://es5.github.com/#x11.6.1

Answer (score 2):

It's because in `n2`, `+` is being treated as concatenation, not addition. So `5` is converted to the string `"5"` and `"4"` is concatenated, giving "54".

Answer (score 2):

When there's a string in either side of `+`, the `+` will be considered as a string concatenating operator, the other side will be converted to string and then do the concatenating.

And be careful of something like `1+2+'3'`, the result is `'33'` rather than `'123'`.

Answer (score 1):

`-` operator has only one meaning - numbers subtraction (or negation and in that case, also conversion to number). In case of `+` operator, however, there are two: number addition **and** strings concatenation. When one of the operands of `+` operator is a string it does string concatenation instead of numbers addition.

The entire process is a bit more complicated than that though and involves an algorithm that you can learn a bit more [here](http://javascript.info/tutorial/object-conversion), for example.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that object-conversion url.

Answer (score 1):

The `+` operator is also a string operator. Quite every basic type variable in javascript can be interpreted also in its string representation. You are just attaching 5 to 4 getting 54.

The `-` operator is not a string operator so the compiler tries to interpret "4" as a number, thus getting 1

Answer (score 1):

Javascript takes 5 as a number and "4" as string.
The javascript + operator use to concat two things.
If you want to addition please use parseInt.

```
var n1 = 5-"4";
var n2 = parseInt(5)+parseInt("4");

alert(n1);
alert(n2);
```