# update/add localStorage with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to save the user's clicks in the localStorage and then when the user comes back and clicks the localStorage will add the new clicks.

This is what I have:

```
var storedClicks = localStorage.getItem("clicks");

  function count_clicks()
{
    var count = parseInt(document.cnt_click.cnt_clicks.value);
    count++;
    document.cnt_click.cnt_clicks.value = count;
    localStorage.setItem("clicks", storedClicks + count);
        if(count == 10) {
           alert(document.cnt_click.cnt_clicks.value);
        }
        $('#printHere').html(storedClicks);

}
```

But all this does is just adding the number at the end, so lets say this is the user's click history:

Visit 1: 2 clicks
Visit 2: 6 clicks
Visit 3: 3 clicks

The output will then be 263 clicks, not 11 clicks. What do I need to change/do and for some reason it won't print the clicks.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This should do it: `localStorage.setItem("clicks", +storedClicks + count);` or `var storedClicks = +localStorage.getItem("clicks");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
var storedClicks = localStorage.getItem("clicks");
localStorage.setItem("clicks", storedClicks + count);
```

with

```
var storedClicks = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("clicks"));
var newCount = storedClicks + count;
localStorage.setItem("clicks", newCount);
```

You were appending int to string.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It makes more sense now. Didn't think of that, and I didn't see the problem until you pointed it out. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var storedClicks = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("clicks"));
```

You added string to integer:

"12" + 3 = "123" // string

Comment: Thanks, but Mystic Magic was sooner than you so @Mystic Magic gets the right answer

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned you concatenated strings instead of adding numbers.
This is a common mistake done by users new to javascript.

Also see [Javascript (+) sign concatenates instead of giving sum of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961000/javascript-sign-concatenates-instead-of-giving-sum-of-variables) for further reading.

Please see my example:

```
storedClicks++; // this will cast the string to a number
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LdjE6/6/

I hope this makes it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" onclick="count_clicks()" />
<div id="sc"></div>

<script>
function count_clicks()
{
    var storedClicks = (localStorage.getItem("clicks") == "undefined" || localStorage.getItem("clicks") == null) ? 0 : parseInt(localStorage.getItem("clicks"));
    localStorage.setItem("clicks", storedClicks + 1);
    $('#sc').html(parseInt(localStorage.getItem("clicks")));

}    
</script>
```

Above is tested code.