# Why is number + string a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, type-conversion, addition

Sort of trying out some quirks in javascript:

First I did

```
console.log("5" + 1);
```

This prints 51, this is normal right, both number and string have a + operator, but since string is the first variable it will convert 1 to a string.

Now when I did this:

```
console.log(1 + "5")
```

I expected output to be 6, as I thought it would convert string to a number. 
However, the magic output was 15.

Could anyone more experienced in javascript brighten this up for me?

Comment: An addition (even of different types) that follows the [commutative law](http://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/commutative-law.html) isn't a bad thing in general ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961000/javascript-sign-concatenates-instead-of-giving-sum-of-variables (first one found, I'm sure there are many out there)

Comment: @linqu Expect that it is *not* commutative because `"5" + 1 == "51" != "15" == 1 + "5"`.

Comment: It makes more sense than [some other uses of the `+` operator in JavaScript](http://destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat).

Comment: That's indeed some weird behaviour

Comment: @Bakuriu good point! I was referring to the data type that does not change. But it's true, result is changing

Comment: It gets concatenated no matter what, as long as there's a string parameter.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Quoting ECMAScript spec [The Addition operator ( + ) section](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1):

> 7. If Type(lprim) is String **or** Type(rprim) is String, then
>       Return the String that is the result of concatenating ToString(lprim) followed by ToString(rprim)

So the order doesn't matter here.

Comment: Beat me to it...The general rule is:  If you add a number and a string, the result will be a string!

Comment: Aye, an odd rule though

Comment: Why odd? If there is a string, then the result is going to be string as well. Easy to remember. It would be weird if result depended on the order of operands, I think.

Comment: Unfortunately, when an operator can be reused the language designers have to chose a rule for each case. IMO this is better than `2 + "Hello"` becoming `2 + the ascii value for "Hello"`.

Comment: It seems more logical to me to be honest, why would String take precedence over number?

Comment: Well, to me more logical would be `NaN`.

Comment: @RobinHellemans: When it comes to default operator precedence, apart from those that comes naturally from mathematics, you can't reason about their behavior. In these cases, the specification simply enforces the behavior.

Comment: @Joshpbarron: What the heck is "the ASCII value for 'Hello'"??

Comment: 072 101 108 108 111 @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'm sure there's a way in PHP to make `2 + "Hello" = 2 + the ascii value for "Hello".` Have to look it up. :P

Comment: Again, there is no ASCII value for "Hello". There is a value for each of its constituent characters, which is not the same thing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, for the sake of 1,000,000 comments, you are correct.

Answer (score 8):

> console.log(1 + "5")
>   I expected output to be 6, as I thought it would convert string to a number. ...

But then what would you expect if you had written the following?

```
console.log(1 + " fine day")
```

or

```
console.log(1 + " answer(s) to my question")
```

There can be no assurance as a general rule that a string is convertible to a number.  But any number can be converted to a string.  That's why the conversion rules are written to move toward a type that is compatible.  (In contexts where you as a programmer know that a string can be safely converted to a number, then you can do so explicitly so that the + operation is between two numbers.  But that is not true in general for strings.)

In other contexts, this is also why small ints and low precision floats would be converted to large ints or double precision floats when operating on mixed types that the latter types.  You can safely convert the limited forms into the larger forms, but you cannot safely go in the other direction in general.  A small int can be represented as a big int or a double, but the other direction is not generally a safe conversion.

So conversion rules for operation on mixed types are written as much as is feasible to move toward mutually compatible types that are safe common types.  It is left to the programmer to write explicit conversions for the special cases where a more general type can be safely converted to a more limited type.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases the value will be converted to a string. 
When you add a number to a string or a string to a number, the result is a string.

Simply use `parseInt(value)` or `toString(value)` to force the conversion.

Comment: Good answer except no citations!

Answer (score 1):

You can try code :
      `console.log(1 + parseInt("5"))`
=> 6

Answer (score -6):

Concatenation also uses `+` in Javascript.

```
var result = "String" + number + obj;
// is equivalent to
string result = "String" + number.ToString() + obj.ToString();
```

However thing is, in C# / .net you could do the same thing, and you will get the same result - `System.Console.WriteLine("result is " + 10 + 20);`.

In JavaScript (and C# for that matter) strings are immutable. They can never be changed, only replaced with other strings. You're probably aware that combined + "String" doesn't directly modify the combined variable - the operation creates a new string that is the result of concatenating the two strings together, but you must then assign that new string to the combined variable if you want it to be changed.

The argument about using mathematical operators to do string concatenation is arguably an "incorrect" argument, but there's also an argument to be made that using + to do a lot of string concatenation can be very slow.

Comment: "but there's also an argument to be made that using + to do a lot of string concatenation can be very slow." this isn't very true anymore. http://jsperf.com/string-concat-without-sringbuilder/5 which I got linked from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4717855/829835)

Comment: How does this even answer the question?

Comment: I don't understand why so much downvote, was just giving a simple explanation to OP on his/her question!!! What the f*ck!!

Comment: the comment from @nhahtdh explains the downvotes. You're not answering the question. The question is _not_ about using mathematical operators for string concatenation like you assumed.

Comment: If that's the case, how come OP selected it as answer in the 1st place? only when you started downvoting that he changed the answer!!