# Different Javascript behavior on substraction and sum

Tags: javascript

Why such thing would happen in Javascript?

```
'5'+3 = 53
'5'-3 = 2
```

Comment: Because the language specification says so?

Comment: '5' is a string and + is used for string concatenation, so when using + with a string it will concatenate

Comment: have you tried jquery?

Comment: @atmd What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: Sorry, it was an attempt at humour

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037997/why-is-number-string-a-string-in-javascript?lq=1)

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because + operator is overloaded. If any operand is a string, string concatenation is performed. If you have two numbers, addition is performed.

In other words

```
2+3=5
```

while `'2'+3='23'` and `2+'3'='23'`.

On the other hand, for the - operator, it is not overloaded in such a way and all operands are converted to numbers.

```
'8'-2=6
```

because `-` is not overloaded and operand '8' will be converted to 8. Hence, we get 6.

For further information on this, please have a look [here](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.6.1) and read the paragraphs 11.6.1 and 11.6.2.

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation is done with + so Javascript will convert the first numeric 5 to a string and concatenate "5" and "3" making "53".

You cannot perform subtraction on strings, so Javascript converts the second numeric i.e. "3" to a number and subtracts 3 from 5, resulting in "2" as the result.