# javascript adding number to width()

Tags: javascript

I want to add 20px to the width of a property that is autogenerated.
I found this post but I can't seem to find the appropriate solution for my problem.
[Javascript (+) sign concatenates instead of giving sum of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961000/javascript-sign-concatenates-instead-of-giving-sum-of-variables)

this is my code:

```
settings.autowidth ? $(self).width() : settings.width;
```

settings.autowidth = true, so this will return $(self).width() which is 151px.

When I want to add 20 px like this, I get 15120px

```
settings.autowidth ? $(self).width()+'20px' : settings.width;
```

The solution in the above mentioned link says I need to add some brackets, But I don't know where to place them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for the `px`.

When you added the `px` and the quote `'` you are saying add the text `'20px'` of the width in this case 150 so you end up with the effect of adding two strings.

To have the values treeted as numbers remove the quotes `'` and the `px`.

```
settings.autowidth ? $(self).width() + 20 : settings.width;
```

Comment: Indeed, I probably have tried all possibilities except this one... (I thought I have tested this as well though) Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @KevinRovers If you mark the answer as the accepted answer, green tick on the left, then it will help other users in future, you also get a small bit of rep +2 for accepting answers :)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to count a string with a number.
Basically you're doing this:
`"string" + 150`
Which would result in `"string150"`;

Correct way of doing this is:
`settings.autowidth ? $(self).width() + 20 : settings.width;`

Answer (score 1):

The value of `$(self).width()` is not the string `"151px"`, it's the number `151`.

Just add `20` to the number:

```
settings.autowidth ? $(self).width() + 20 : settings.width;
```

If you want it in the format `"171px"` then you add the `px` to it:

```
settings.autowidth ? ($(self).width() + 20) + 'px' : settings.width;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a little utility function:

```
function addPx( orig, val ) {
  var noSuffix = orig.split('px')[0];
  return (Number(noSuffix)+val) + "px";
}


alert(addPx("30px", 10)); // 40px
alert(addPx("0px", 20)); // 20px
```