# Javascript: "+" sign concatenates instead of giving sum of variables

Tags: javascript, variables, sum, concatenation

I am currently creating a site that will help me quickly answer physics questions.
As it happens, the code didn't run as expected, here is the code

```
if (option == "dv") {
    var Vinitial = prompt("What is the Velocity Initial?")
    var acceleration = prompt("what is the acceleration?")
    var time = prompt("what is the time?")

    Vfinal = Vinitial + acceleration * time

    displayV.innerHTML = "v= vf= " + Vfinal + "ms" + sup1.sup();
}
```

Now, let's say Vinitial was 9, acceleration was 2, and time was 3.
When the code runs, instead of getting 15 for "Vfinal", I get 96.
I figured out that it multiplies acceleration and time fine, and then just concatenates the 9 at the beginning, with 6 (the product of 2 * 3).

I have fixed it for now by using

```
Vfinal =  acceleration * time - (-Vinitial)
```

which avoids using the "+" sign, but I don't want to have to keep doing this. How do I fix it?

Comment: Convert the value from strings to int

Comment: `Vfinal = + Vinitial + acceleration * time` - extra `+` at the start to enforce numerical operations.

Comment: Each of your values `Vinitial`, `acceleration` and `time` are strings _not numbers_. As such this is defined behaviour. Try parsing the strings... e.g. `Number.parseInt(Vinitial)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript (+) sign concatenates instead of giving sum of variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961000/javascript-sign-concatenates-instead-of-giving-sum-of-variables)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are dealing with `strings` here, and math operations on strings will mess up. Remember **when ever you are doing math operations you have to convert the data into actual numbers and then perform the math**.

Use **`parseInt()`** [more Details here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

Your code should change to

`Vfinal = parseInt(Vinitial,10) + parseInt(acceleration,10) * parseInt(time,10);`

**Edit 1:** If the numbers are **decimal values** then use **`parseFloat()`** instead

So the code would be

`Vfinal = parseFloat(Vinitial) + parseFloat(acceleration) * parseFloat(time);`

Comment: I am literally just starting with JS, when I use the code suggested, any kind of decimals I use, are ignored in the final result, which I do not really want.
I tried reading up on "parseInt()", but it didn't help me much.

Comment: @KeaneCarotenuto you need to use `parseFloat()` if you are playing with decimal values

Answer (score 2):

> **[Object-Oriented JavaScript - Second Edition](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/object-oriented-javascript-second-edition)**: As you already know, when you use the plus sign with two numbers, this
>   is the arithmetic addition operation. However, if you use the plus
>   sign with strings, this is a string concatenation operation, and it
>   returns the two strings glued together:
>
> ```
> var s1 = "web";
> var s2 = "site";
> s1 + s2; // website
> ```
>
> The dual purpose of the + operator is a source of errors. Therefore,
>   if you intend to concatenate strings, it's always best to make sure
>   that all of the operands are strings. The same applies for addition;
>   **if you intend to add numbers, make sure the operands are numbers**.

You can use "+" operator with `prompt()` to convert returned values from string to int

```
var Vinitial = +prompt("What is the Velocity Initial?");
var acceleration = +prompt("what is the acceleration?");
var time = +prompt("what is the time?");
```

**Explanation:**

```
var a = prompt('Enter a digit'); 
typeof a; // "string"
typeof +a; // "number"
```

If you will enter non-digit data `+a` gives you `NaN`. `typeof NaN` is `"number"` too :)

You will get the same result with `parseInt()`:

```
var Vinitial = parseInt(prompt("What is the Velocity Initial?"), 10);
var acceleration = parseInt(prompt("what is the acceleration?"), 10);
var time = parseInt(prompt("what is the time?"), 10);
```

> [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt): **parseInt(string, radix);**
>
> - **string**: The value to parse.
> - **radix**: An integer between 2 and 36 that represents the radix (the base in mathematical numeral systems) of the above mentioned string.
>     Specify 10 for the decimal numeral system commonly used by humans.
>     Always specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and to
>     guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce
>     different results when a radix is not specified, usually defaulting
>     the value to 10.

**Epilogue:**

> **[Object-Oriented JavaScript - Second Edition](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/object-oriented-javascript-second-edition)**: The safest thing to do is to always specify the radix. If you omit the radix, your code
>   will probably still work in 99 percent of cases (because most often
>   you parse decimals), but every once in a while it might cause you a
>   bit of hair loss while debugging some edge cases. For example, imagine
>   you have a form field that accepts calendar days or months and the
>   user types 06 or 08.

**Epilogue II:**

> ECMAScript 5 removes the octal literal values and avoids the confusion
>   with parseInt() and unspecified radix.

Comment: Most of this made no sense to me, as I am just starting out with JS, and haven't learnt much about it, but I still decided to give this a go.
My problem with using "parseInt()", was that decimals were ignored, which is probably not very useful.
So, I just ended up using 

    var Vinitial = +prompt("What is the Velocity Initial?");
    var acceleration = +prompt("what is the acceleration?");
    var time = +prompt("what is the time?");

and just left the rest of my code. It seems to work fine, so I guess it's alright?

Thank you for this though, I'm sure I'll understand it soon. :)

Comment: @KeaneCarotenuto, Yes you are right. `+promt()` can help you in many cases. It can help to do your code more compact and elegant (: . You can learn JavaScript with **Object-Oriented JavaScript - Second Edition** book. This book was very useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is, Your value has been took it in a form of string .. so convert your value into Int using **parseInt(accelaration)**.. then it will work ..

```
Vfinal = parseInt(Vinitial) + parseInt(acceleration) * parseInt(time)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
//use ParseInt
var a=10,b=10;
var sum=parseInt(a+b);
```

ex:

```
parseInt(Vinitial + acceleration) * time
```

Comment: it should be `var sum=parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);`, your solution will give `int: 1010` because first you'll concatenate strings ('10'+'10' = '1010'), and then you'll cast it to number which gives you `int: 1010`

Comment: yes, it gives you 20 because you have `var a=10,b=10;`. Change it to `var a='10', b='10';` (as main question says) and check it again