# Why does the addition (plus) operator produce a string when the left operand is a number and the right one is a string?

Tags: javascript

As I got several post about this topic and came to know that expression evaluation occurs from left to right that's why `"1"+1 gives "11"` but `1+"1" also gives "11"`, Please explain why?

Which is mentioned in this post and accepted by most of viewers.
[Javascript (+) sign concatenates instead of giving sum of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961000/javascript-sign-concatenates-instead-of-giving-sum-of-variables)

Comment: It is converting the number to a string, over the `Number.toString()` method. Try this: `+"1" + 1`, which will result in `2`. The `"1"` is converted to `+1`. And `1 + 1 = 2`.

Comment: I am not getting reason of downvotes. :/

Comment: Because the question isn't really that interesting. This is me being honest, I didn't downvote, I just think that you find this stuff in every single tutorial online. Maybe others downvote for this reason? I don't know, I'm not one of them.

Comment: Actually confusion came from this answer..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961000/javascript-sign-concatenates-instead-of-giving-sum-of-variables

Comment: Unfortunatelly, the answer is given a bit below. It explains step-by-step why it is happening. Basically: if a string is found, everything is converted to a string. Then it is concatenated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the spec says so. See [The Addition operator (+)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1):

> 7. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8)(*lprim*) is String or [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8)(*rprim*) is String, then
>
>    1. Return the String that is the result of concatenating [ToString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8)(*lprim*) followed by [ToString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8)(*rprim*)
> 8. Return the result of applying the addition operation to [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3)(*lprim*) and [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3)(*rprim*).

So it only matters whether some operand is a string, but not which one.