# Number concatenates instead of being added

Tags: javascript, jquery

Everything works fine on my code until I enter a value for shipping it concatenates to the result instead of addition.

```
function subtotal(){
    var a,b = 0;
    var row = $('#tbody tr').not(':first-child').length;
    for(i=0;i <= row;i++){
        a = parseFloat($('#i-total'+i).val());
        b += a;
    }
    $('#sub-total').val(parseFloat(Math.round(b * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));
    $('#sub-total').attr('value',parseFloat(Math.round(b * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));

    var dis = $('#disc-val').val();
    $('#disc-val').attr('value',dis);
    var tax = $('#tax').val();
    $('#tax').attr('value',tax);
    if(tax == '' || dis == ''){
      tax = 0;
      tax = parseFloat(tax);
      dis = 0;
      dis = parseFloat(dis);
     }
    var stat1 = $('#disc-val').attr('data-stat');   
    if(stat1 === 'on'){
        b = b-(b*dis/100);
        // console.log('disc%'+z);
    }
    else if(stat1 === 'off'){
        b = b - dis;
        // console.log('disc'+y);       
    }
    var stat2 = $('#tax').attr('data-stat');    
    if(stat2 === 'on'){
        b = (b*tax/100)+b;
    }
    else if(stat2 === 'off'){
        b = b + tax;
    }

    var ship = $('#shipping-val').val();    
    $('#shipping-val').attr('value',ship);
    if(ship == ''){
        ship = 0;
        ship = parseFloat(ship);
    }

    b = (ship + b);     

    $('#whole-total').attr('value', b);
}
```

Comment: How do we execute this ? Kindly put only relevant code...

Comment: `var tax = parseFloat($('#tax').val()) || 0;`

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to add 'string' + number. Try `+'somestring' + num`.

Comment: Or just `+$('#tax').val();`.. @Satpal — You got quite sharp vision....

Comment: `tax` and `dis` needs to be parsed Float

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript (+) sign concatenates instead of giving sum of variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961000/javascript-sign-concatenates-instead-of-giving-sum-of-variables)

Comment: Im am trying to add numbers but when it comes to shipping it concatenates instead of adding. I tried to parsefloat the number but also its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use below way

```html
 if(ship == ''){
        ship = 0;
        ship = parseFloat(ship);
    }

    b = parseFloat(ship) + parseFloat(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `ship` is a string if it's not empty.

Should this

```
if(ship == ''){
    ship = 0;
    ship = parseFloat(ship);
}
```

be

```
if(ship == ''){
    ship = 0;
} else {
    ship = parseFloat(ship);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ship value is mishandled here :

```
var ship = $('#shipping-val').val();    
$('#shipping-val').attr('value',ship);
if(ship == ''){
    ship = 0;
    ship = parseFloat(ship);
}


if(ship == ''){
    ship = 0;
}
else{
  ship = parseFloat(ship);
}
```

or it can be as

```
var ship = $('#shipping-val').val();    
$('#shipping-val').attr('value',ship);
if(ship == ''){
    ship = 0;
}

var ship = $('#shipping-val').val();    
$('#shipping-val').attr('value',ship);
if(ship == ''){
    ship = 0;

}


ship = parseFloat(ship); // out of conditional statement
```