# Why is "5" + 2+3 and 2+3+ "5" different in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Why is "5" + 2+3 and 2+3+ "5" different in JavaScript?

This if giving me wrong result.

```html
<p>The result of adding "5" + 2 + 3</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  x = "5" + 2 + 3;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
</script>

<p> result of adding 2+3+"5"</p>
<p id="qwe"></p>
<script>
  y = 2 + 3 + "5";
  document.getElementById("qwe").innerHTML = y;
</script>
```

Comment: What's the right result? What were you expecting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does adding String with Integer work in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40848551/how-does-adding-string-with-integer-work-in-javascript)

Answer (score 8):

`+` evaluates left-to-right, so

```
"5" + 2+3
```

is equivalent to

```
("5" + 2) + 3
```

and the other one:

```
2+3+ "5"
```

is equivalent to:

```
(2 + 3) + "5"
```

When two numbers are `+`d together, they are added, so the result is a number. But if either side of the `+` is a string, the two expressions are *concatenated* instead of added. So

```
("5" + 2) + 3
// results in
'52' + 3
'523'
```

```
(2 + 3) + "5"
// results in
5 + '5'
55
```