# Numbers adding next to each other (ex. 123 + 123 = 123123)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

So I have like kind of a homemade economy thing and when I added a working command and when it works it picks a random number and stuff but when it adds the number to the old currency it's adding like for ex 123+123 = 123123 when it supposed to be 246 I don't know how to fix this I tried everything and nothing has worked for me

```js
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefixS.prefix + 'work')) {
    const inventoryS = await inventory.findOne({ userID: message.author.id, guildID: message.guild.id });
    if (inventoryS.item1 === 'true') {
      const payment = Math.floor(Math.random() * 125) + 25;
      inventoryS.currency += payment
      inventoryS.save()
      message.channel.send({ embeds: [new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle('After a long day of work your balance is').setDescription(`__Your balance__\n > Money: ${inventoryS.currency}`).setColor('BROWN')] })
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of them must be `Number`s to do addition, otherwise it will add as strings

```js
inventoryS.currency = parseInt(inventoryS.currency) + parseInt(payment)
```

Comment: i did this but its adding like more numbers like 123 + 123 = 257

Answer (score 4):

it is possible that your `inventoryS.currency` is a string value

```js
let a = '123'     //a string
let b = 123      //an integer
a += b
console.log(a)   //logs 123123
```

you will need to parse it to an integer before adding

```js
let a = '123'
let b = 123

a = parseInt(a) + b
console.log(a)
```

more references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40848551/how-does-adding-string-with-integer-work-in-javascript)