# How JavaSCript '+' operator work with string and number?

Tags: javascript

How am I getting 339 as output of the following code ?

```js
console.log(3 + '4' + 5 - 6)
```

can anyone please explain me?

Comment: duplicated

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40848551/how-does-adding-string-with-integer-work-in-javascript#:~:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20the%20%2B%20operator%20is,string%20and%20concatenates%20both%20together.

Answer (score 2):

`3 + "4"` yields `"34"` due to the implicit string conversion. Implicit string conversion seems to have higher priority than implicit number conversion.

`"34" + 5` yields `"345"`

`"345" - 6` yields `339` due to the implicit number conversion

Comment: "*Implicit string conversion seems to have higher priority than implicit number conversion.*" no, it's just processed left-to-right and that's the first operation: `1 + 2 + "3"` is `"33"` because the first operation is `1 + 2` and then it's `3 + "3"`. There is no priority of conversions.

Comment: If there's no string in play, there's no need for conversion.

Comment: You said that there was some priority to the conversion. There isn't. It's just processing the operations in sequence. And a `<number> + <string>` will always convert to a string.