# Sum totals within an Array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

When calculating values within an Array I am getting this: total = "0212.16967.04".
The correct total in this example is:1179.20

```js
function calculateSum(){
  //build array of numbers
  amtArray = [];
  $('.amount').each(function (index, value) {  
    amtArray.push($(this).text()||0);
  });
  //calculate all values and return results  
  var sum = sumArray(amtArray);
  console.log('sum ->', sum)
}
 
function sumArray(input) {
  var total = 0;
  for (idx=0; idx <= input.length-1; idx++) {
    total += input[idx];
  }
  return total;
}

calculateSum()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="amount">212.16</div>
<div class="amount">967.04</div>
```

Should output: 1179.20

Comment: Try `"212.16" + "967.04"` on the developer console - it's string concatenation. Convert to `number` before using the `+` operator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript (+) sign concatenates instead of giving sum of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961000/javascript-sign-concatenates-instead-of-giving-sum-of-variables)

Comment: use parseFloat()  `$('.amount').each(function (index, value) {     
    amtArray.push(parseFloat($(this).text())||0);
});`

Answer (score 4):

You need to cast the value from string to number with an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) (or by using `Number` or `parseFloat`, or any other operator which expects a number), otherwise if any of the operands is a string, all parts are treated as string and concatinated.

```
total += +input[idx];
//       ^
```

Answer (score 2):

The error here is you are concatenating strings, here's a solution:

```js
var array = ["212.16", "967.04"]

function sumArray(input) {
  var total = 0;
  for (idx = 0; idx <= input.length - 1; idx++) {
    total += parseFloat(input[idx]);
  }
  return total;
}

console.log(sumArray(array));
```

Answer (score 1):

In the function `sumArray` you can directly return the result of [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) using [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) to work with numerical values:

```js
const sumArray = arr =>  arr.reduce((a, b) => a + Number(b), 0);

console.log(sumArray(["212.16", "967.04"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating string values rather than adding flowing pointing numbers.  You can use parseFloat() to convert from string to float like this this:

```
function sumArray(input) {  //input = (2) ["212.16", "967.04"]
    var total = 0;
    for (idx=0; idx <= input.length-1; idx++) {
        total += parseFloat(input[idx]);    
    }
    return total;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using a unary, parsefloat, Number you should also use toPrecision to get that last zero you indicated in your question

```js
var val = document.getElementsByClassName('amount');

function calculateSum() {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
    var value = val[i].textContent;
    total += +value;
  }
  return total.toPrecision(6);
}
val[1].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', calculateSum());
```

```html
<div class="amount">212.16</div>
<div class="amount">967.04</div>
```