# Angular number gets interpreted as string, table pagination

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

In order to introduce pagination of a table I created pagination component.
Although currentPage type is number, calling method nextClicked() leads to string addition like: "01111" instead of 4.

```
export class PaginationComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() totalItems: number;
  @Input() itemsPerPage: number;
  @Input() currentPage: number;

  @Output() setPrevious = new EventEmitter<number>();
  @Output() setNext = new EventEmitter<number>();
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  prevClicked() {
    if (this.currentPage > 0) {
      this.currentPage = this.currentPage - 1;
    }
    this.setPrevious.emit(this.currentPage);
  }
  nextClicked() {
    this.currentPage += 1;
    this.setNext.emit(this.currentPage);
  }
}


<button 
class="btn btn-primary"
(click)="prevClicked()">Prev</button>
<p>Page {{ currentPage }}</p>
<button 
class="btn btn-primary"
(click)="nextClicked()">Next</button>
```

Using pagination component in parent:

```
<pagination
    [totalItems]="totalItems"
    itemsPerPage=10
    currentPage=0
    (setPrevious) = "setPage($event)"
    (setNext) = "setPage($event)">
</pagination>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript (+) sign concatenates instead of giving sum of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961000/javascript-sign-concatenates-instead-of-giving-sum-of-variables)

Comment: use parseInt method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
nextClicked() {
    this.currentPage++;
    this.setNext.emit(this.currentPage);
}
```

Comment: thanks. I know the + operator can also be used for concatenations but to me it's really weird because I forced currentPage to be of type number by declaration..

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be working. If it is not working then only reason can be that in runtime, parent component is assigning the 'currentPage' input to this component is as a string value.

Answer (score 0):

Try `this.currentPage = this.currentPage + 1;`instead of `this.currentPage += 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you should bind itemsPerPage and currentPage as expressions (namely put them in brakets [ ]) like:

```
<pagination
    ...
    [itemsPerPage]="10"
    [currentPage]="0"
    ...>
</pagination>
```