# Why (4 + 5 + "6") is 96 but ("4" + 5 + 6) is 456 on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

`console.log(4 + 5 + "6");
console.log("4" + 5 + 6);`

I think it is something related to element type(string, number)
But I can not find the proper document explaining this concept.

Comment: based on the first operand's type it is evaluated as a sum, or concatenation?

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839/ Briefly said if there is a number on the left it would convert to number everything else, if string is on the left vice versa happens

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript (+) sign concatenates instead of giving sum of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961000/javascript-sign-concatenates-instead-of-giving-sum-of-variables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever a number and a string are added together, the number turns into a string. Because of this adding `4` and `5` will equal `9`, because they are both numbers, but adding `4.toString()` and `5.toString()` will result in `45`, because the `+` operator isn't actually adding, it is joining two strings.

When you do `console.log(4 + 5 + "6");`, the numbers 4 and 5 are being mathematically added first, which is 9, and then 9 gets converted into a string and 6 gets added on to it.

When you do `console.log("4" + 5 + 6);`, the number 5 gets converted into a string and joined to the string "4". Same thing happens with the 6. This results in the string 456.

Like @Pointy said, this can be changed by changing the order of operations. Parenthesis will be calculated first. For example, `console.log("4" + (5 + 6));` will result in 411, because the 5 and 6 will be mathematically added first, then converted into a string and added on to 4.

Great question, and I didn't think about that until today :)

Answer (score 2):

Most operators in JavaScript expressions are evaluated left to right, so `4 + 5 + "6"` is interpreted as `(4 + 5) + "6"`. Thus the numeric addition is performed first, followed by the string concatenation. In the second example, the left-most operand is a string, so both `+` operations are string concatenation.

Comment: Yes, precedence between operators also has very important effects on evaluation.

Comment: I like how parenthesis can do so many different things in javascript, and not just what they do in math. It's cool how parenthesis can be used for `&&` and `||` conditions as well.

Comment: @programmerRaj the *expression grammar* of any programming language is basically its heart and soul, and in JavaScript it's very flexible. (Not the *most* flexible, perhaps, but pretty good.)

Comment: Not really a programming language, but I hate it when people use brackets in math to group things, because it voilates javascript math syntax.